# What does origin mean in git, and what do I misunderstand?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I just started using bitbucket and I think I got a problem understanding the structure of it.

For me, I have a new repo called ABC, I added some basic filed, commit and push origin master. Now The latest push is my origin/master, right?

Now I wanna create a branch called D and work on it. When I finished the work, I commit, and now I wanna push this logically to my master. I don't wanna push it to origin. For me it looks like I have to push everything to origin and I don't understand why. For me Origin is like a milestone, but I wanna keep the origin on the first push my basic project build.

Then I'm going to create a branch E and work on it. Finally, for me the structure should be like this.

Here a small picture hopeful to show how I think:

http://s7.postimg.org/k1f5q4b13/git_explanaition.jpg

[image]

**Update**: For those of you who understand German https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Im_FrvLxXo this also helped me alot understanding the system.

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your terminology is confusing. You don't push things to branches. You merge things into branches. You push to *remote*s.

`origin` is the name of your *remote*. In simple terms, that's a repository you have cloned from. Here's an example where there are two remotes:

```
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/git-publish/git-publish$ git remote -v show
github  git@github.com:abligh/git-publish.git (fetch)
github  git@github.com:abligh/git-publish.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/stefanha/git-publish.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/stefanha/git-publish.git (push)
```

(don't worry about the separate entries for fetch and push). You can see I cloned `stefanha`'s github repo called `git-publish`, then having made some changes pushed it to my own github repo (same name).

So you merge between your local branches, and push/pull/fetch from remote repositories. A fetch fetches changes from a remote repository, and a pull (roughly) fetches then merges them into a local tracking branch. A push merges your changes to the local copy of the remote repo and pushes your changes to the remote repo.

If you create a new branch `D`, and have committed a change set to it, then there are two things you could do with it (well, there are probably more, but let's stick with the obvious):

- You could merge the branch `D` into your local master. You might or might not then wish to push master to origin.
- You could push `D` to origin, so origin now has two branches. To do this, the first time you need to tell git where to push, i.e. do `git push -u origin D` rather than just `git push`. The `-u` tells it to track the upstream branch, i.e. pull from there when you next do a `git pull`.

I've simplified a bit here, but that's basically it.

Comment: So if I understood this right, "origin is the name of your remote." means origin is my actual local build, and git push origin to_whatever mean I push my actual local stuff to whatever. So clone does clone and create an branch?

Comment: Nope. `origin` is where you push to and pull from (or more precisely one of the places you push to and pull from). In my case above it was stefanha's gitub repository. In your case it's probably your bitbucket repository. `origin` is precisely *not* your local repository.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot. I hope it's much clearer for me now. I also watched an 67 minutes presentation  about git to get better into it. For those who understand German the link which hopeful helped me :-) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Im_FrvLxXo

Answer (score 2):

You don't "push" to master, you "merge."  The "git push" command is for sending to another clone of the same repo (usually on another machine), not for moving commits between branches in the same clone of the repo.

Comment: Im not sure if the picture is working right now. If it is, can you take a look on my view of the structure if it's right or not? - Ahh, I think I got it now. But if I do this, doesn't this mean I cannot go back ever? Or is it possible to go back with the master?

Comment: Your picture was previously embedded, now it's a link and the picture itself seems tiny and hard to read.  Let's just use text.  ;)

Comment: I marked the comment from @abligh as answer - your comment also helped me a lot to understand the basic system, he due to his effort I marked his one. Thanks anyway. Have a good day.