# When i "git push origin local-branch", where is the remote branch refered that i want to push my changes to?

Tags: git, github, git-push

```
git push origin local-branch
```

What does "origin" mean here? assuming that no upstream is set for my current branch "local-branch". In my perspective, "git push remote-branch" should do the job, since git should understand that i want to push the currently checked branch i.e "local-branch" to "remote-branch". So, in essence, we just need "remote-branch" as an argument to "push" command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does origin mean in git, and what do I misunderstand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045857/what-does-origin-mean-in-git-and-what-do-i-misunderstand)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889346/what-does-git-remote-mean

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+what+does+origin+mean

Comment: Besides the linked questions and larsks' answer, note that if you want to ask the other Git (at the URL stored under the remote name `origin`) to set *its* branch `world` when pushing *your* branch `hello`, you would write: `git push origin hello:world`. The `hello:world` thing here is a *refspec*, two names separated by a colon, with your local branch name on one side, and the other Git's branch name on the other side.

Comment: With only one name—`git push origin hello`—the missing colon and second name tells `git push` "we use the same branch names", more or less. (It's more complicated in some weird situations, which you should avoid if possible and they won't come up unless / until you start looking for trouble. :-) )

Answer (score 1):

> What does "origin" mean here?

That refers to a *remote* in your local repository.  A remote is a label for a remote repository, and is created either implicitly when you run `git clone` or explicitly when you run `git remote add`.

A repository can have multiple remotes (for example, you will often have a remote referring to the upstream version of some code and another referring to your own remote fork of that repository).

> In my perspective, "git push remote-branch" should do the job, since git should understand that i want to push the currently checked branch i.e "local-branch" to "remote-branch".

If you haven't previously set up tracking information (either implicitly, by checking out a remote branch locally, or explicitly, using `git push -u ...`), then you need to tell git where to push your branch.

When you `git push origin local-branch`, you are telling `git` to push your local branch named `local-branch` to a remote branch of the same name hosted at `origin`.